# How do I obtain the following layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to obtain the following layout in android: http://i54.tinypic.com/iz8enk.png

Where in the white space I'm having an imageview.My Image will stretch until the bottom of the screen where I have 2 buttons.
I tried with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
  <ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/myPic"
    />
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:background="#000000">

    <Button 
    android:text="Retake Photo" 
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </Button>

    <Button 
    android:text="Confirm Photo"
    android:id="@+id/confirm"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="98dip" >
    </Button>

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But unfortunately my screen looks like this:
http://i53.tinypic.com/291i6id.png.

So how do I achieve that?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    < LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/introLayout" >
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

android:scrollbars="none"
>

    <ImageView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:id="@+id/myPic"
/>


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ></Button>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        ></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I worked with this.Except I used ScrollView Instead of LinearLayout and a webView instead of Button.It worked for me

Comment: @george Does this approach work now? If it doesn't, it should not be the accepted answer as that will often stop other users from answering.

Comment: Almoust works.I made a few changes, but is the closest of truth:)

Answer (score 1):

In relative layout place the imageView on top and then those buttons should be placed using align_parentLeft = true and align_parentRight = true with layout_below = "id of imageview". Try this and let me know...

Comment: I tried and it's obvious that the image won't stretch on the whole screen...:P

Comment: set layout_width="fill_parent" in imageview.

Comment: I did...the problem is with the height!!!If I put layout_height="fill_parent" then I won't see the buttons!

Comment: I did and it looks like this: http://i53.tinypic.com/30nekc8.png Now tell me what should I do for the imageview to come down?

Comment: sorry I did not get your point. Now what do you want to do with imageview or button?Do you want to give some space or what?Please explain.....

Comment: @vineetska let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2121/discussion-between-george-and-vineetska)

Answer (score 1):

First Create an xml menu file as mainmenu.xml in your android project. and past this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="Exit"
        android:menuCategory="container" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exit" />
    <item android:id="@+id/update" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_update"
        android:title="Update"></item>
</menu>
```

Also past this code below to your java code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater infMenu = getMenuInflater();
    infMenu.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {
        UninAndroSMSActivity.this.finish();
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.update) {
        startActivity(new Intent(UninAndroSMSActivity.this,
                UninAndroSMSActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: In the future, please don't open two answers. Instead, edit your original answer using the `edit` button on the bottom left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` for the LinearLayout with the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:id="@+id/exit" 
  android:title="Exit" 
  android:menuCategory="container" 
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exit" /> 
<item android:id="@+id/update" 
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_update" 
  android:title="Update" />
</menu>
```